# remove backslash from json - WP REST API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I am extending Wordpress Rest API. While building the APIs I see backslash even after adding json flags to remove them.
What I am doing is below

```
stripslashes(json_encode(['success'=> true], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_HEX_APOS));
```

Output

```
"{\"success\":false}"
```

Is there something I am missing above?
I'm using PHP 7+

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the flags `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` and `JSON_HEX_APOS`? I mean if you just do

```php
$json = json_encode(['success'=> true]);
echo $json;
```

it prints out valid json.

Even with your flags if you just output the json it runs completely fine without `\`.

```php
>>> echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
{"success":true}⏎

>>> echo json_encode(['success' => true], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
{"success":true}⏎

>>> echo json_encode(['success' => true], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
{"success":true}⏎
```

So I suspect something in your output script that adds these `\`.